# How come my spring mvc web app works without pom.xml?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I have removed pom.xml from my eclipse project folder.
And I choose run on server option and everything works fine.
I am new to Spring MVC and have been given this project as an interview round.
Spring version 4.0.6, Tomcat 7, Eclipse Juno

Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pom.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) is the build configuration file for the Maven building tool, Using Maven is optional as you can use any building tool of choice, for example Ant, Maven, Gradle ... etc

The idea behind this build configuration file is that you can define all your dependencies of your project (Spring, Struts, Hibernate, ... etc), source code repository, test cases classes, `war file` generation info, any other configuration for your project. and If you want to give me your project, you could only give me that `pom.xml`, and I would simply run `maven` on this file, and it will download your source code and dependencies, run test cases, build war file and deploy it on application server.

For more information, check the `POM` reference [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html)

Comment: Thanks ... this explains a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`pom.xml` is a maven configuration file. You don't need it to run a Spring MVC application.

Having said this, sin maven is what you usually use to build a project, you are not going to be able to build it again if you removed the `pom.xml` file.

Comment: But then in case I have to add dependencies like hibernate validation and all (which did not work for me and I had to use validator concept) .. So how do i set it up?

Comment: @DarkKnight Restore the pom.xml and get a maven book or read some tutorials about the subject.

Comment: Thank you .. I will certainly take a look

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

- You did not reference any Spring MVC class in your Web Appliction
- Your Tomcat already has the Spring MVC in its libraries
- Spring MVC libraries are copied in your Lib folder of your Web project, so they are carried along within the war (or exploded by the Tomcat plug-in for Eclipse).

As [Pablo pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25047312/3231778), you do not need Maven to add dependencies to your projects.